# IIS - Prevent browsing an application from other machines

Tags: iis

I installed IIS on my machine (laptop), and added an new application.
All works fine, but I need to be display my application just locally and prevent browsing it from other machines.
Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The are several ways to achieve this, but the simplest solution is to block incoming requests using a firewall.

I suppose you use the default Windows Firewall and your web application is listening on the TCP port 80. So open an administration interface (command **wf.msc**), select "Inbound rules", locate the rule "World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-in)" and disable this rule.

Other ways to achieve the same result:

- Using the "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" IIS module with appropriate rules for requests filtering
- Modifying site's bindings in IIS (set IP address for example to 127.0.0.1)